# Rgl package 3D scatter plot removing scientific notation from axes

Tags: r, rgl

Is there any way to turn off the scientific numbering of the axes in rgl when doing a scatter plot? I attack an image of what I get below, and I don't want the e+004 but the full number

[image]

Below is my code:

```
library(rgl)

# Add a new column with color
mycolors <- c('royalblue1', 'darkcyan', 'oldlace')
comb_data$color <- mycolors[ as.factor(comb_data$mg) ]

# Plot
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot3d( 
  x=comb_data$a, y=comb_data$b z=comb_data$c, 
  col = comb_data$color, 
  type = 's', 
  xlab="a", ylab="b", zlab="c")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `plot3d()` call, you can say `axes = FALSE`, then have a separate call to set the axes to whatever you want.  Your example isn't reproducible, but here's something similar.  This version has axes that move around as you rotate the display.  Use `axes3d()` for static axes instead.

```
comb_data <- data.frame(a = c(0, 1500), b = c(0, 1e4), c = c(0, 7e4), color = c("royalblue1", "darkcyan"))
plot3d( x=comb_data$a, y=comb_data$b, z=comb_data$c, 
        col = comb_data$color, 
        type = 's', 
        xlab="a", ylab="b", zlab="c", axes = FALSE)
xat <- pretty(comb_data$a)
yat <- pretty(comb_data$b)
zat <- pretty(comb_data$c)
bbox3d(xat=xat, yat=yat, zat=zat, col=c("white","black"), 
       front="culled", back="culled")
box3d()
```

You can use the `xlab` argument to `bbox3d` to give strings to use at the `xat` locations if you don't like the defaults (which are produced by `format(xat)`), and similarly for the other axes.